# Nest.js: initialization of property from controller's superclass

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, jestjs, nestjs

I have a question regarding unit testing controllers in Nest.js framework. Problem is that property from a superclass is not initialized in the controller class when creating a test module.

This is a sample code I'm talking about:

```js
export class MyController extends SomeOtherController {

    // Inherited from SomeOtherController
    async initSomeObject() {
        this.someObject = await initializeThisSomehow();
    }

    async controllerMethod(args: string) {
        // Do something
    }

}

export abstract class SomeOtherController implements OnModuleInit {

    protected someObject: SomeObject;

    async onModuleInit() {
        await this.initSomeObject();
    }

    abstract async initSomeObject(): Promise<void>;
}
```

And this is how I've created my test

```js
describe('MyController', () => {
  let module: TestingModule;
  let controller: MyController;
  let service: MyService;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [],
      controllers: [MyController],
      providers: [
        MyService,
        {
          provide: MyService,
          useFactory: () => ({
            controllerMethod: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve()),
          }),
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    controller = module.get(MyController);
    service = module.get(MyService);
  });

  describe('controller method', () => {
    it('should do something', async () => {
      jest.spyOn(service, 'controllerMethod').mockImplementation(async _ => mockResult);
      expect(await controller.controllerMethod(mockArgs)).toBe(mockResult);
    });
  });
});
```

Now, if I were to run the application in development mode, the `someObject` property would get initialized, and code works. But when running tests, it seems like the test module is not initializing it (so it is undefined).

Any sort of help is much appreciated.

Comment: Where is `initStuff()` (`SomeOtherController`) called?

Comment: My code was missing crucial details: the `initStuff()` method is actually called `onModuleInit()` and it comes from the `OnModuleInit` interface which is part of `@nestjs/common`. I apologize for making a mistake of not being more careful. Question is updated.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In your test's before each you need to run the following

```
await module.init(); // this is where onModuleInit is called
```

It's also best to close the application

```
afterEach(async () => await module.close());
```